# Trying to make Multiple EMA but getting Syntax Error in Pine Editor

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ARsW.png) Syntax Error

I am trying to make 5 Ema's for my stategy but Getting Syntax Error. Hopefully someone can provide the solution for the error

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right code in the screenshot? What Pine version you are using? Pls paste full code here as a text, so we can check it. This error should not appear with code provided.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces as the first character at the beginning of lines 12-20, spaces that are not a multiple of 4 at the beginning of a line are considered a continuation of the previous line, so all your code from line 11 to line 20 is considered one line.

More about line wrapping at [Pine Manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Script_structure.html#line-wrapping)